# Sham gift scheme to evade foreign buyer tax

Tags: tax-law, new-zealand, real-property, foreign-relations

Reading the National party's [intention](https://i.stuff.co.nz/national/politics/300962097/nationals-foreign-buyers-tax-could-cause-international-dispute-with-china-and-others) to impose 15% tax on foreigners buying property in New Zealand, I wonder if the following scheme could well flourish if that plan came to reality.

Say Yáng, a foreigner to New Zealand, wants to buy a $10M property in it. He would have to pay $1.5M tax.

To evade that, he makes a deal with Zhāng, New Zealand resident: Yáng transfers $10.1M to Zhāng who buys the property in his name for $10M, pockets $100k and then *gifts* the property to Yáng.

Would there be any efficient legal leverage for the Government to deal with such a scheme?

Comment: A contract that contains a clause in the form of "I give you $100k, you give me that property for free" sounds not only a bit suspicious.

Comment: @PMF Let's assume that Yáng and Zhāng trust each other, and no one else gets to know about their "contract".

Comment: That's not a gift, that's a sale. Yáng owes the government 15k. However, the **land register** will need to know about the contract.

Comment: @Trish Of course it's not a gift when you know all the facts. The question is whether/how the Government will sufficiently prove it in law to stop the scheme.

Comment: I think in Germany there is a rule that even written contracts don't count if reality is different. If one gives the other 10 millions as a present, and the other buys a property, and gives it back to the first guy as a present, then a judge will look at it and say "you claim it is a contract about presents. I look at would really happened and it was a foreigner purchasing property for 10 million".

Comment: A more likely scenario is that a local company is created to own the property, and then Yang gets a controlling share in the company. See https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/oct/03/tony-and-cherie-blair-bought-property-via-offshore-firm-and-saved-300000-in-tax for a similar scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tax you have described has not been implemented, so we can't look to the law imposing it for specific anti-avoidance provisions. However, since gifts are not taxable as income, sham gifts are an established method of tax evasion. If the foreign buyer tax is introduced, it would likely be enforced by the same office and in the same manner as income tax.

In the example  you have given, Zhang has received $10.1 million and may be asked to explain why that amount is not liable to income tax. The receipt could be traced through Zhang's bank account to the real estate purchase, and if the subsequent "gift" of real estate to Yang was registered on the title, the tax office would have enough information to identify and tax the substance of the transaction, a purchase by Yang using Zhang as agent. (Zhang would owe income tax on their fee of $100,000, and would probably also have broken a law requiring them to report that they were purchasing on behalf of a foreign buyer.)

In the real world, if Yang sought to illegally avoid tax and scrutiny of their investments using a secret nominee, the "gift" would not be registered on the title. Instead, Zhang would hold and manage the property on Yang's behalf, and find some way to covertly transfer the benefit to Yang without attracting scrutiny. Yang, having given their money to Zhang for an illegal purpose, could not rely on the courts to enforce the trust if Zhang decided to breach it.

Comment: Looks like you've mixed up the roles of Yáng and Zhāng lol.

Answer (score 1):

### Property transfer taxes are generally levied on sale price *or* market value whichever is the greater

Because if you can think of the scam, the lawmakers can too.

So Zhāng can gift the property, it doesn’t save Yáng any tax.

Usually, there are exceptions for inheritance or where the beneficial owner doesn’t change such as a property entering or leaving a trust.

Comment: I didn't know that one has to pay tax in cash upon receiving non-cash gifts. Which specific law is this?

Comment: @Greendrake stamp duty on real estate and cars in NSW is levied on price or market value whichever is the greater